# How to escape characters like \n and \t in a JSON response by default using Spring Boot and Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I'm having problems to return a JSON with escaped characters from a Spring Boot application (version 2.7.13).

The `/demo` endpoint in the following example code:

```java
package com.example.invalidjson.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public class DemoController {
        @GetMapping(path = "/demo")
        Demo getExample() {
            Demo demo = new Demo();
            demo.setTitle("Example of \n JSON");

            return demo;
        }

        @GetMapping(path = "/read")
        void readExample() {
            try {
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                Demo demo = objectMapper.readValue("{\"title\" : \"Example of \n JSON\"}", Demo.class);

                System.out.println("Reading succeeded: " + demo.getTitle());
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Demo {
        private String title;

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
    }
}
```

returns the following JSON:

```json
{"title":"Example of \n JSON"}
```

The problem is that this JSON can't be parsed by other clients. Even Jackson fails to read it. The `/read` endpoint throws the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value
 at [Source: (String)"{"title" : "Example of
 JSON"}"; line: 1, column: 25]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:2391) ~[jackson-core-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:735) ~[jackson-core-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase._throwUnquotedSpace(ParserBase.java:1110) ~[jackson-core-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._finishString2(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2155) ~[jackson-core-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._finishString(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2126) ~[jackson-core-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.getText(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:320) ~[jackson-core-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:41) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:11) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:314) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4674) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3629) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3597) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.example.invalidjson.demo.DemoApplication$DemoController.readExample(DemoApplication.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
...
```

It was my understanding that [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), as the default JSON parser of Spring Boot, would automatically escape characters like `\n` and `\t` as per the [documentation](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/json/JsonReadFeature.html#ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER), or maybe I didn't understand the documentation so well.

I've see some options using `JacksonConfiguration` like:

```java
package com.example.invalidjson.demo;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.io.IOException;

@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        JsonSerializer<String> stringJsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
                generator.writeString(value.replace("\n", "\\n"));
            }
        };

        SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
        simpleModule.addSerializer(String.class, stringJsonSerializer);

        objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Isn't there a different way to handle that?

And the underlying question is: Why is Jackson generating a JSON that not even itself can read?

Comment: "The problem is that this JSON can't be parsed by other clients." The JSON you've shown us is absolutely valid, assuming it genuinely contains a backslash followed by n. Rather than show us the code producing the valid JSON, please provide the code that fails to deserialize it - using hard-coded JSON in a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet, it is my understanding that \n is a control character that represents new line. The escaped version of it would be \\n, but I could be wrong. At least this what I was expecting to get in the response from Spring. 
It seems like it is also what Jackson expects as it returns “Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value” when trying to parse that JSON with it.

Comment: Yes, you're wrong. the escaped version of the control character is just `\n`. `\\n` represents a backslash followed by n, that's all. It's really, really important to distinguish between "the characters in the string" and "the text in a string literal" (which itself uses escaping). A *string literal* representing a JSON string would use `\\n` because the JSON itself contains a backslash followed by an `n` - but you shouldn't see a double backslash in the JSON itself Again, you should really provide a [mcve] of parsing a hard-coded JSON string.

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet, I updated the code example with the parsing of the JSON generated by Jackson.

So when you say:
"A string literal representing a JSON string would use `\\n` because the JSON itself contains a backslash followed by an `n` - but you shouldn't see a double backslash in the JSON itself"
My difficulty to understand here is that why Jackson expects `\\n` but returns `\n`?

If I try to serialize an object with the string `Example of \n JSON` in other languages, it returns in fact `Example of \\n JSON`. So, what is missing on my code to have the same behaviour with Jackson?

Comment: This code is broken: `objectMapper.readValue("{\"title\" : \"Example of \n JSON\"}", Demo.class)`. That is not the same as the JSON you've shown after "returns the following JSON". Your string literal contains a line break; the JSON you've shown contains a backslash followed by an n. Print both of those to the console with `System.out` and you'll see the difference. I'm sure that Jackson doesn't expect a `\n` in the actual JSON - but if you want to represent the JSON *as a string literal* then you do indeed need `\\n`. But print that to the console - you won't see the double backslash.

Comment: (To highlight what I'm saying about the JSON not being the same - note how in your string literal you're escaping all the double quotes, but those *aren't* escaped in the three-line JSON you've shown. In other words, you've been inconsistent about how you've converted the JSON into a string literal.)

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet, I appreciate you are trying to help but I think we are going off track here. The three-line JSON in the question is just formatted so people can read it better. Sorry if that confused you, the raw format would be `{"title":"Example of \n JSON"}`. 
But just to try what you suggested, I tried:
```
System.out.println("Original object: " + demo.getTitle());
System.out.println("Example of incoming JSON: {\"title\" : \"Example of \n JSON\"");
```

And the result is:
```Original object: Example of
 JSON
Example of incoming JSON: {"title" : "Example of
 JSON"```

Comment: I don't think this *is* off track. I think the cause of the whole problem is you getting confused between the actual content of a string, and its string literal representation (and potentially the representation as shown in the debugger). However, it looks like I'm not able to communicate that clearly, so I'll step away from this question now. Best of luck (no sarcasm intended) getting it resolved.

Comment: No problem @JonSkeet, it is probably lack of understanding on my side and wrong expectation towards Jackson. I don't see any difference in the `System.out`, but thanks for the help! If I find the reason or what I'm doing wrong, I will update here in the future.

Answer (score -1):

To escape characters like \n and \t in a JSON response by default using Spring Boot and Jackson, you can configure the ObjectMapper used by Jackson to enable the JsonGenerator.Feature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII feature. This feature escapes non-ASCII characters using Unicode escape sequences, which includes characters like \n and \t.

Here's how you can do it:

Create a configuration class to customize the Jackson ObjectMapper:

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() {
    return builder -> {
        builder.featuresToEnable(JsonGenerator.Feature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII);
        // Add any other Jackson customization if needed
    };
}

@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer customizer) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    customizer.customize(objectMapper);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

}

In the above configuration class, we define a bean for Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer that enables the JsonGenerator.Feature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII feature.

We also define a bean for the ObjectMapper itself, where we apply the customizer to configure the ObjectMapper instance.

With the above configuration in place, Spring Boot will use the customized ObjectMapper to serialize JSON responses. The \n and \t characters (along with other non-ASCII characters) will be escaped with Unicode escape sequences.

Note: Ensure that you have Jackson dependencies already configured in your Spring Boot project.

That's it! Now your JSON responses should include escaped characters like \n and \t by default.

Comment: The JSON in the question *already* escapes the new line character...

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet, isn’t the escaped version of \n actually \\n? I have this assumption because Jackson says \n isn’t escaped. And because I’ve seen a second backslash added when dealing with \n in JSON strings, for example in Python and JavaScript. I am not an expert on the topic, perhaps I have the wrong expectation based on past experiences with different languages.

Comment: @lbodevan: Your original text doesn't contain `\n` though - it contains a linefeed. You'd only see two backslashes if you wanted to represent an *actual backslash* followed by n. The text in `Demo` as created by `return new Demo("Example of \n JSON");` doesn't contain any backslashes.

Comment: Hi @zargham-irtza, thanks a lot for the response. I tried that and actually doesn't compile. `customizer.customize(objectMapper);` fails to compile because it expects a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`. I managed to make it compile anyway, to try the feature `ESCAPE_NON_ASCII` but it didn't help.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow, Zargham irtza.

It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the latest policies since your answer appears likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). As a heads-up, [posting of AI-generated content is not permitted on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).

If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.